# Trocar direção da flecha do menu ao abrir o submenu

Tags: css

E possível somente com *CSS* fazer trocar a direção da flecha do menu quando abrir o submenu?

Acredito que a pergunta seria como detectar o *click* no menu.

Estou usando o `toggleClass()` do *jquery* para fazer isso, mas gostaria de usar só *CSS*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso adicionando o atributo `tabindex` à `div` e alterando a imagem da flecha (considerando que a imagem seja um `background`) quando a `div` receber `focus`:

```css
div{
 display: block;
 width: 100px;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 padding: 10px;
 background: url(https://www.uni.edu/unicalendar/profiles/uni_default_install/modules/custom/uni_blocks_antares/images/down_arrow.png) no-repeat 90%;
 background-size: 20px;
}

div:focus {
 background: url(https://www.ukcommunityfoundations.org/wp-content/themes/ukcf/images/layout/up-arrow.png) no-repeat 90%;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="1">
   Menu
</div>
```

Comment: No meu caso depois que eu abrir o menu e eu clicar de novo nele, o submenu se fecha, mas a flecha não muda pq o focus continua nele. Teria como contornar isso?

Comment: @DiegoVieira É preciso saber então oq é essa seta: é um background, é uma imagem, é um pseudo-elemento?

Comment: @DiegoVieira Ou melhor, como é aberto e fechado esse submenu? É uma função?

Comment: @DiegoVieira O CSS apenas não consegue detectar click, ela apenas consegue alterar o estilo do elemento diante de um evento: focus, hover, checked etc.

Comment: Utilizo o :before para colocar a flecha e o menu abre através de uma função. A tua solução funciona, mas só quando eu clico fora do menu, preciso que quando eu clique em cima ela também funcione.

Comment: @DiegoVieira O ruim de trabalhar com pseudo-elements é que vc fica meio limitado. Veja neste [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ao11qarc/) que, em vez de utilizar :before, utilizando um <span> fica bem mais fácil.